# I can't see the no Referral Exclusion List in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to stop self referrals by adding my site to the Referral Exclusion list but I can't find it anywhere. I used this [Google help document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en-GB).

Could this be because I have not upgraded to Universal Analytics?

What are the reasons for self referrals?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that you need have upgraded to Universal Analytics to even be able to see this feature.   Here is a screenshot from one of my properties that *has* been upgraded to Universal:

[image: referral exclusion list]

Here is the screenshot from one of my properties that has not been upgraded to Universal:

[image: tracking info]

Without Universal analytics, there is no sub-menu when you click on Tracking info.  The referral exclusion list is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Google Analytics guy but I did go to the page you cited.

Yes. This feature requires Universal Analytics.

As well, from what I can imagine, this allows you to focus referrals to just external referrals - that is referrals from other sites. This allows you to see where your referral traffic is coming from.